# Java API to read XML and JSON properties

Tags: java, xml, json, properties

Is there any `Java` open source library to read properties from an `XML` or a `JSON` file, using the same API call, irrespective of the format?

`Java` has the `Properties` class, which offers a `loadFromXML()` method, but does not support `JSON`.

The ideal case would be a library that handles either `XML` or `JSON` on its own, i.e. without the calling code having to specify whether the properties to be loaded are expressed in `XML` or `JSON`.

Comment: My question makes it obvious that the problem I am trying to solve is reading properties from either and XML or a JSON file, without having to know the format. It also makes it obvious that I have tried the Properties class with loadFromXML(), which is not up to the spec. So, the question remains: instead of having to write such a method, is there any library that handles it?

Comment: Why not just ask how to read properties from either XML or JSON without knowing the format, then?

Comment: That is exactly what I am asking and it would have been much more productive if we focused on the question, instead of running an exercise in downvoting. As if there are no hundreds of questions in StackOverflow discussing tools already!

Comment: Classic XY question, though. You wanted to do X, but you asked for Y.

Comment: Nope, but if this is your interpretation, so be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Jackson 2.0 All details presented by this [link](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2012/03/entry_467.html)

Comment: Jackson needs to know the format of the properties. I was looking for a library that can tell on its own and load accordingly. Nevertheless, +1 and thanks for the answer. :-)